# Prove that the series $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)-\cos(4x)...$diverges

Tags: calculus, analysis

$F(x)=\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)-\cos(4x)...$

Do you know how to prove that this infinite series diverges?

Comment: Just take $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, simple, at x=0, we have 1-1+1-1+1...

Comment: Is there any other tests that one can use on this one?

Comment: Which is divergence. If it's converges to $f(x)$ then there is a value $f(0).$ But it's not so.

Comment: On wikipedia page of Grandi's sum, it says that the Cesaro sum of this series is 1/2. Could 1/2 be be the Cesaro sum of this trigonometric series?

Comment: Maybe, but $f(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: According to Riemann-Labesgue lemma, as the series you present is a Fourer series with coefficients $a_n=\pm 1$ which does not tend to $0$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$, then if the series was converging, it wouldn't be towards a locally integrable function.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first run through a careless argument someone might make for why the series converges: $$F=\Re\exp ix\sum_{n\ge 0}(-\exp ix)^n=\Re\frac{\exp ix}{1+\exp ix}=\frac12.$$The problem is our common ratio $-\exp ix$ has modulus equal to the radius of convergence, so convergence isn't assured.

The case $x=0$ gives Grandi's series, which doesn't converge in the usual partial-sums sense because the terms $\pm 1$ don't $\to 0$. Nor will that happen if $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, since then $\cos nx$ will be $\pm 1$ infinitely often. Finally, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos nx=0$ cannot be true if $x/\pi$ is irrational either, as then $nx$ is arbitrarily close to a multiple of $\pi$ infinitely often.